# Who has legal responsibility for uninspected changes?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, renovation, inspection

I've been involved in some siding work on a home I bought recently that included replacing the sheathing. This exposed some electrical and plumbing work done during prior renovations that I don't think was ever inspected. Although I'm neither a plumber or an electrician the work doesn't look all that good. The inspection for the work that I'm doing, including the sheathing will only happen after the walls are complete again. If I don't get the prior work checked either by an inspector or a professional prior to sealing the wall back up, who would be the legally responsible party for the prior renovation work that was never inspected?

Comment: Once you know about, as the owner it comes onto you.  You might be be able to go back to the old owners if they did the work and did not report it, but this becomes more for lawyers.  Work not looking good is probably something you do not want to seal up again.

Comment: When you say, “not good”, are we talking about burn-the-house-down type violations? If so, just get it fixed and move on.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate That's what I'm not sure about and which is haunting me as I seal things back up.

Comment: Post pictures of the not good and someone here will you to run away or just messy work.

Comment: You could look for a history of prior permits and inspections on your house with the LAHJ office in charge of those things, perhaps. I've seen plenty of ugly work that passed inspection, and some pretty work that was wrong, and probably wasn't inspected or it should have failed.

Comment: This is a lawyer question. I imagine that that your lawsuit could be negatively impacted by you having noticed the bad work and publicly acknowledging that you chose not to fix it. If it's somebody else suing, then I expect that it's between them and whoever performed the bad work. During real estate transactions there are disclosure forms, though, that could land you on the hook after this public acknowledgement.

Comment: You, now that you're leaving it the way it is.  Don't forget pipe insulation… places that "never freeze" might now, ask Texas about that.